How to play sounds directly into the Microphone in Python?
I have a program, similar to Soundpad. Currently, it plays sound through Virtual Audio Cable (VAC).
However, the users must manually install VAC and set the sound source to "Audio Cable Out" in every application where they want to use my program.
I want to simplify my program so that the user doesn't have to do anything, and the sound is played directly into the "Microphone" device, just like in the original Soundpad.
I only know Python, and even the lowest-level libraries do not allow write() to an input_device.
I also know that it's possible to import custom C++ code in Python, but I’ve never done that before.
How can I implement this idea?
import pyaudio
import audio_metadata
import numpy as np


def play_sound(audio_file):
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    metadata = audio_metadata.loads(audio_file.read())
    audio_file.seek(0)
    stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                  channels=metadata.streaminfo.channels,
                  rate=metadata.streaminfo.sample_rate,
                  output_device_index=SETTINGS["OUTPUT_DEVICE"],
                  output=True)
    
    chunk = SETTINGS["CHUNK_SIZE"]
    data = audio_file.read(chunk)
    while data:
        datachuck = np.frombuffer(data, np.int16)
        datachuck = datachuck * SETTINGS["VOLUME"]
        datachuck = datachuck.astype(np.int16)
        datachuck = datachuck.tobytes()

        stream.write(datachuck)
        data = audio_file.read(chunk)

    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()



There is no universal way to force any application to use a particular audio endpoint. If you want your program to do it, you need either to find application's API (if any), or modify application's settings (in the Registry or in Application Data). But if the application doesn't offer an API to change settings, modifying them from your app may be considered malicious.

BTW, the virtual audio software you pointed to, is called VB-Cable. Virtual Audio Cable (VAC) software is a different product. Please don't confuse them.

If you want to create your own virtual microphone, you need to write your own audio driver.
